# Issue with pie and combined charts in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin Forms application(for android and ios) I am using xlabs.forms.charting to display 2 different charts.First by default pie chart should appear after clicking on next button in the same screen combined chart should appear.similarly prev button should work.But in my case charts are not appearing properly.The same code is working properly for sometimes and sometimes displaying blank screen while clicking on next and prev buttons.Can anyone help me to solve this problem.please find my below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
x:Class="AndroidTest.ChartsView" 
xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms.Charting">
<ContentPage.Content>




  <StackLayout x:Name="stacknextprev" Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image x:Name="prevImg" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                            <OnPlatform.iOS>Images/prev2.png</OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <OnPlatform.Android>prev2.png</OnPlatform.Android>
                            <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                            </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>


                <Image x:Name="NextImg" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
                            <OnPlatform.iOS>Images/next2.png</OnPlatform.iOS>
                            <OnPlatform.Android>next2.png</OnPlatform.Android>
                            <OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                            </OnPlatform.WinPhone>
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout x:Name="stackpie" Padding="5" BackgroundColor="Fuchsia">
            <charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" >
            </charting:Chart>
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="stacktest" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Aqua">
        </StackLayout>



</ContentPage.Content>
```

And my CS Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Xamarin.Forms;

using XLabs.Forms.Charting;

using XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls;


namespace AndroidTest
{
public partial class ChartsView : ContentPage
{


    int testcountnew=0;
    Series firstBarSeries;
    Chart chart;

    public ChartsView ()
    {
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar (this, false);

        //code to check network Availability


        InitializeComponent ();

        //testcountnew = 0;
       GeneratePieChart ();



        TapGestureRecognizer NextImageClicked = new TapGestureRecognizer {

            Parent = this,
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            TappedCallback = (view,args) =>
            {
                testcountnew++;
                //DisplayAlert("","Testing","Cancel");
                if(testcountnew==1)
                {
                   GenerateCombinedChart();
                   NextImg.isVisible=false; 
                }



            }

        };
        NextImg.GestureRecognizers.Add(NextImageClicked);

        TapGestureRecognizer PrevImageClicked = new TapGestureRecognizer {

            Parent = this,
            NumberOfTapsRequired = 1,
            TappedCallback = (view,args) =>
            {

                //DisplayAlert("","Testing","Cancel");
              count--;
               if(count==0)
                 {
                            GeneratePieChart();
                          prevImg.isVisible=false;
                      }    

            }

        };
        prevImg.GestureRecognizers.Add(PrevImageClicked);
}

    public void GeneratePieChart()
    {

        PieChart.IsVisible = true;
        stacktest.IsVisible = false;
        PieChart.WidthRequest = 300;
        PieChart.HeightRequest = 400;

         firstBarSeries = new Series
        {
            //Color = Color.Red,
            Type = ChartType.Pie
        };


        firstBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = FieldChart,Color=Color.Blue,Value = 20 });
        firstBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = FieldChart1,Color=Color.Fuchsia,Value = 30});
        PieChart.Series.Add(firstBarSeries);

    }


    public void GenerateCombinedChart()
    {

            stacktest.IsVisible=true;
            PieChart.IsVisible=false;
            stackpie.IsVisible=false;
            Series firBarSeries = new Series
            {
                Color = Color.Red,
                Type = ChartType.Bar
            };
            firBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Jan",   Value = 25});
            firBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Feb",   Value = 40});
            firBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "March", Value = 45});

            Series secondBarSeries = new Series
            {
                Color = Color.Blue,
                Type = ChartType.Bar
            };
            secondBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Jan",   Value = 30 });
            secondBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Feb",   Value = 35 });
            secondBarSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "March", Value = 40 });

            Series lineSeries = new Series
            {
                Color = Color.Green,
                Type = ChartType.Line
            };
            lineSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Jan",   Value = 27.5 });
            lineSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "Feb",   Value = 37.5 });
            lineSeries.Points.Add(new XLabs.Forms.Charting.Controls.DataPoint() { Label = "March", Value = 42.5 });

             chart = new Chart()
        {
            Color = Color.White,
            WidthRequest = 300,
            HeightRequest = 400,
            Spacing = 10
        }; 

            chart.Series.Add(firBarSeries);
            chart.Series.Add(secondBarSeries);
            chart.Series.Add(lineSeries);

           stacktest.Children.Add(chart);


    }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your code can't be compiled, please fix it or explain what is `count`.

Comment: Sorry that is "testcountnew" not count.